# Audio problems on X1 Carbon, only Mono Audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, mono

Thank you in advance for assistance with this.  This issue is driving me a bit nuts, in looking for a resolution.

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed on the X1 Gen2.  Latest updates applied.  DKMS driver installed as well.  I have tried manually adjusting the mixer, ran through various patches, etc. and I still come back to the same issue.  Sound only on the left hand side.I've even had the internal sound card (module) replaced on the laptop to no avail.

`amixer` turns up the following:

```
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]

Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

I cannot seem to switch this to stereo.  When I plug into an external sound card, stereo audio works just fine.  When I plug the laptop into an HDMI display, the stereo audio works as well.

ANY suggestions are appreciated on this.
Thank you again.

Comment: This would up being a re-install to resolve the issue, with the latest 4.4 kernel update..